# HW indentificator, replaced BIOS chip

Tags: laptop, bios, hp-pavilion

got a problem with installing drivers in Windows since I have replaced faulty BIOS chip. Unfortunately chip seller sent me a chip from another notebook. But PC is running and I was able to install integrated (intel) graphic card. But not the dedicated (AMD) on board one. Because of driver package not beeing matched by HW identificator.

Any1 how suggestion what to do? It was the only web I found exactly same chip (at least according to description -_-) as my notebook is. HP Pavilion dv6-6155ec, but I get HP Casablanca H510 instead read in BIOS setup.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Return the chip and get the correct one.

Comment: Purchase identical parts, or at least parts, that are compatible with your hardware.

Comment: Well, I did purchased identical parts, but get different instead. It was month of postage + soldering by another person.